# Actual document size limit for Azure Cosmos DB’s API for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

## Description

I was doing some testing and found out that maximum document size limits of CosmosDB seem inconsistent with the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#per-item-limits

### Test SQL

1. Create a Cosmos DB Core (SQL) database
2. Try to insert an item of **2093334** bytes into "Items" table

- It succeeds since it is: `< 2Mb` as stated in the official documentation (link above)

3. Now I try to insert a larger item of **2239798** bytes into the same table

- It fails with error code (413) since the item is `> 2Mb`

> RequestEntityTooLarge error occurred: Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException : Response >status code does not indicate success: RequestEntityTooLarge (413); Substatus: 0; >ActivityId: c1977df8-ec39-40b9-bd69-6e6a40ff6c00; Reason: (Message: {"Errors":["Request >size is too large"]}

*Conclusion*: Results **match** the documentation

### Test MongoDB

1. Create a Cosmos DB (MongoDB) database
2. Try to insert an item of **2093334** bytes into "Items" collection

- It succeeds since it is `< 2Mb`

3. Now I try to insert an item of **2239798** bytes into the same collection

- It **still succeeds** even though it is `> 2Mb` and the documentation states differently (or I am missing something)

4. Now I try to insert an item of **4520606** bytes into the same collection

- **Still succeeds** even if it is ~4.31Mb and

5. Finally when I try to insert an item of **4526027** bytes into the same collection

- It fails with error code (413):

> ERROR: MongoDB.Driver.MongoWriteException: A write operation resulted in an error. >WriteError: { Category : "Uncategorized", Code : 16, Message : "Error=16, Details='Response >status code does not indicate success: RequestEntityTooLarge (413); Substatus: 0; >ActivityId: 8f20b261-e1c5-4ca9-b4e6-6cbc5352ce7e; Reason: (Message: {"Errors":["Request >size is too large"]}

*Conclusion*: Results **do not match** the documentation

#### NOTE

The number of bytes was calculated in the following way:

```
var itemStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(itemStr);
Console.WriteLine($"total num of bytes: {bytes.Length}");
```

Regarding the successful write of a large item into MongoDB, I also verified through mongoshell that the stored document is larger than 4Mb:

```
Object.bsonsize(db.Items.findOne({_id:ObjectId("61dec458316798c759091aef")}))
```

## Question:

1. Is there any other place in the documentation which defines these sizes differently?
2. Am I not interpreting these results correctly?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB has a binary storage format that compresses the data. The amount of compression depends on the shape of data within your documents. Documents with deeper hierarchies tend to compress more than those which are flatter. As a result, you are able to store uncompressed data greater than the documented 2MB limit.

While it is possible to store more than 2MB of uncompressed data with Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB this is not something I would recommend as it is impossible for you to know what amount of compressed data you will have before being inserted.

I also should point out that in general, you will have better performance in terms of cost and latency with higher numbers of smaller documents than you will with larger sized documents (this applies to native MongoDB as well). So as you model your data for your application, keep that in mind.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, shouldn't the 'Object.bsonsize(db.Items.findOne({_id:ObjectId("61dec458316798c759091aef")}))' from the mongoshell show me the compressed size?

Comment: What does it show you now?

Comment: I don't have the exact number at hand, but was showing similar values to the size of UTF-8 encoding i.e. around 4MB. I can provide the exact numbers tomorrow

Comment: 4MB would be the uncompressed size. Whatever it is on the backend would have to be < 2MB.

Comment: I see, is there a way to get the compressed size?

Comment: There's no way to get at it. This all happens in the back-end storage layer.

Comment: Ok thank you, but then again, what is the rule of thumb for storing large documents? If the document is larger than 2Mb with UTF8 encoding, then you should not be storing it in CosmosDB (even if it could succeed when MongoDB variant is in use) ?

Comment: The rule of thumb is to try to avoid designing such that you have large documents. Smaller documents are more efficient on RAM and CPU to process, especially at high volumes. Even Mongo advises this, https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/schema-suggestions/reduce-document-size/

Comment: unfortunately, making documents smaller is not possible. Guess I will have to reconsider the chosen storage type